# Refactoring out `clone` when Copy trait is not implemented?

Tags: rust

Is there a way to get rid of `clone()`, given the restrictions I've noted in the comments? I would really like to know if it's possible to use borrowing in this case, where modifying the third-party function signature is not possible.

```
// We should keep the "data" hidden from the consumer
mod le_library {
    pub struct Foobar {
        data: Vec<i32>  // Something that doesn't implement Copy
    }

    impl Foobar {
        pub fn new() -> Foobar {
            Foobar {
                data: vec![1, 2, 3],
            }
        }

        pub fn foo(&self) -> String {
            let i = third_party(self.data.clone()); // Refactor out clone?

            format!("{}{}", "foo!", i)
        }
    }

    // Can't change the signature, suppose this comes from a crate
    pub fn third_party(data:Vec<i32>) -> i32 {
        data[0]
    }
}

use le_library::Foobar;

fn main() {
    let foobar = Foobar::new();
    let foo = foobar.foo(); 
    let foo2 = foobar.foo(); 
    println!("{}", foo);
    println!("{}", foo2);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ae6334c6c611b2b9f1973e944f763fd9)

Comment: Just removed clone(): https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9a0b4133c06fdf0dcb09decfe39e2c3e

Comment: @MaxV Thank you, unfortunately it was my incomplete example that makes your fix work in this case. I've updated the snippet and the playground link. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your `foo()` method accepts `&self`, it is not possible, because the

```
pub fn third_party(data: Vec<i32>) -> i32
```

signature is quite unambiguous: regardless of what this `third_party` function does, it's API states that it needs its own instance of `Vec`, by value. This precludes using borrowing of any form, and because `foo()` accepts `self` by reference, you can't really do anything except for cloning.

Also, supposedly this `third_party` is written without any weird unsafe hacks, so it is quite safe to assume that the `Vec` which is passed into it is eventually dropped and deallocated. Therefore, unsafely creating a copy of the original `Vec` without cloning it (by copying internal pointers) is out of question - you'll definitely get a use-after-free if you do it.

While your question does not state it, the fact that you want to preserve the original value of `data` is kind of a natural assumption. If this assumption can be relaxed, and you're actually okay with giving the `data` instance out and e.g. replacing it with an empty vector internally, then there are several things you can potentially do:

1. Switch `foo(&self)` to `foo(&mut self)`, then you can quite easily extract `data` and replace it with an empty vector.
2. Use [`Cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html) or [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html) to store the data. This way, you can continue to use `foo(&self)`, at the cost of some runtime checks when you extract the value out of a cell and replace it with some default value.

Both these approaches, however, will result in you losing the original `Vec`. With the given third-party API there is no way around that.

If you still can somehow influence this external API, then the best solution would be to change it to accept `&[i32]`, which can easily be obtained from `Vec<i32>` with borrowing.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't get rid of the call to `clone` here.

The problem here is with the third-party library. As the function `third_party` is written now, it's true that it could be using an `&Vec<i32>`; it doesn't require ownership, since it's just moving out a value that's `Copy`. However, since the implementation is outside of your control, there's nothing preventing the person maintaining the function from changing it to take advantage of owning the `Vec`. It's possible that whatever it is doing would be easier or require less memory if it were allowed to overwrite the provided memory, and the function writer is leaving the door open to do so in the future. If that's not the case, it might be worth suggesting a change to the third-party function's signature and relying on `clone` in the meantime.